# Notification of facebook comments loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I'm creating a web app which uses facebook comments.

When the comments are loaded I need to re-size my container to fit the new size including the comments.

I'm looking for an event that's fired when comments are loaded but can't see any reference to anything anywhere. Is there an event, if so how can I access it?

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [FB.event.subscribe()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). You may want to try subscribing to the `xfbml.render` event.  You may also want to resize your container on the `comment.create` and `comment.remove` events as well